# Print out all Strings from TreeSet that meets some requirement?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I'm doing an assignment which I cant seem to make work. The idea is to load a "dictionary" from a .txt file into a treeset, and generate random letters(6-10 letters) and try to construct words from those letters. The program checks to see if the guessed word is in the treeset. But when you are done guessing, you can enter CTRL+Z and the program will end and print out all the possible words that can be made up from the random letters that exist in the dictionary.

My problem is when I enter CTRL+Z, most of the time the program doesnt print all the possible guess-able words, sometimes it does a very few.

What have I missed?

Here is my code:

```
public class AngloTrainer {

TreeSet<String> dict = new TreeSet<String>();
int ranNum;
String randomWord;

public AngloTrainer(String dictionaryFile) throws IOException {
    loadDictionary(dictionaryFile);
    System.out.println(dict.size() + " words loaded from dictionary.txt ");
    Random randNumb = new Random();
    ranNum = (randNumb.nextInt(6) + 4);
    randomWord = randomLetters(ranNum);
    System.out.println("The random letters are: " + randomWord);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess a word!");
    try{        
        while(reader.hasNextLine() != false){
            String gWord = reader.next();
            if(includes(sort(randomWord), sort(gWord))){
                if(dict.contains(gWord)){
                    System.out.println("ok!");  
                }else{
                    System.out.println("not ok!");
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("not ok!");
            }
        }
    }finally{
        reader.close();
        printWords();
        System.out.println("bye");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

//print all the words that can be guessed
public void printWords(){
    for(String words: dict){
        if(includes(randomWord, words)){
            System.out.println(words);
        }
    }
}

//sort the letters in a String alpabetically
private String sort(String s){
    char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(charArray);
    return new String(charArray);
}

//print out the whole dictionary
private void dumpDict() {
    for(String word: dict){
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}

//load the words from .txt file into TreeSet
private void loadDictionary( String fileName ) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
    for (String line; (line = bufRead.readLine()) != null; ) {
        dict.add(line);
    }
    bufRead.close();
}

//generate random letters
private String randomLetters( int length ) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    String letters = "aabcdeefghiijklmnoopqrstuuvwxyyz";  
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(length);
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) 
        buf.append( letters.charAt(randomGenerator.nextInt(letters.length())));
    return buf.toString();
}

//check if one the letters in one string is included in the other one
private boolean includes( String a, String b ) {
    if ( b == null || b.length() == 0 )
        return true;
    else if ( a == null || a.length() == 0 )
        return false;   
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while ( j < b.length() ) {
        if (i >= a.length() || b.charAt(j) < a.charAt(i))
            return false;
        else if (b.charAt(j) == a.charAt(i)) {
            i++; j++;
        } else if (b.charAt(j) > a.charAt(i))
            i++;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    AngloTrainer at = new AngloTrainer("C:/Some/Where/In/Files/dictionary.txt");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTRL+Z sends a SIGTSTP to your program, this is not a particularly good way to end input. It suspends the process instead of ending the input. Use CTRL+D to input an EOT (End Of Transmission) character, which will properly terminate input and let the program progress.

Comment: Thanks for the help!